# COM troubles between two versions of a C# Application

Tags: c#, com

I haven't worked much with COM, so please forgive my ignorance.

Background: I am working on a project in VS 2010.  There is a C# COM DLL integrated into the C# solution, and a Setup/Deployment project as well - the Setup project is set to register the COM .tlb file upon installation.

The problem: A previous version of the C# application, along with it's COM DLL, was present on a PC when someone decided to install the newest version of the C# application, and therefore the newest COM DLL.  When this happened, it broke the COM functionality for both versions of the C# application..or that is what I am assuming has happened.

Is this typical COM/DLL-Hell behavior?  When both C# applications are uninstalled, and then only ONE is re-installed, everything is back to normal - both apparently can't be installed at the same time.

I have tried changed the GUID for the COM DLL project, changing the AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion for the COM DLL project - all with mixed results.  When I change those items, the new install of the application works (great), but now the old C# application doesn't have working functionality.

Note: there are no errors or exceptions thrown when the COM functionality is failing - the COM calls just seem to do nothing.  So it is "silently" failing.

I have been researching this and trying various modifications to no real success...maybe I'm thinking about this the wrong way.  Is there anyone else with more experience on this that could give me some insight?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a merge module to install the com object and its successive versions.  This would allow you to have multiple versions on the same machine.  From Microsoft:

> A merge module is like a snapshot of a particular version of a component. A new merge module should be created for each successive version of a component in order to avoid version conflicts.

Check out this link: [Installer vs. Merge Module Recommendations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0w2est5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried this - maybe I'm doing it wrong, but I get the same symptoms as before. The Merge Module project just seems to be a way of repackaging things to get the same result. Regardless of whether I edit my assembly version or not, the old version of the program still has the visibly missing functionality.

Comment: stariath, try this:  in your C# application go to the reference of you com object and click on it.  In the properties scroll down to Isolated property and choose True.  Rebuild your project.